# send mail to admin if any user click on " get notified when this product is back in stock "

Tags: magento-1.8, stock-status, notify-me

when out-of-stock products become available again in-stock then send automatic mail to user

So How to send email to administrator if any customer click on `Sign up to get notified when this product is back in stock`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you one free module. Go through module code you will get idea how to do.

[Product out of stock subscription](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-out-of-stock-subscription.html)

Comment: I already installed these extension already but it is not working properly in Magento ver. 1.8.1.0

Comment: Then you need to debug it and post error here.

Comment: @Darshan Check email template is there or not

Comment: Go to http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php. input key of magento connect there and download extension

Comment: Error in admin Panel after installed these magento free extension " https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-out-of-stock-subscription.html "

Fatal error: Class 'BusinessKing_OutofStockSubscription_Helper_Data' not found in /home/sitename/public_html/eshop/app/Mage.php on line 547

Comment: Delete files from var/cache folder and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This extension which you are asking about is built-in Magento module ProductAlert (it has also function to inform customer when prices changes). Although it is not working for guests (not - logged) users. Making it work for all visitors is matter of customization. Extending it is not easy, because of restrictions connected with customer id foreign key and methods based on customer model (which can be not available if guest doesn't have account in your shop) - in my opinion it is easier to prepare own extension with separate logic.

I checked this one and I do not recommend it - it's quite outdated.
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-out-of-stock-subscription.html

Comment: Hi lord_of_strings, what is the difference between your answer and above answer? both are same right? please don't post same answers , please remove this.

Comment: I describe some details about this extension, as I have used that